# How to change WebView scale programmatically?

Tags: android, webview, zooming, scale

I'm developing for android using PhoneGap. Following you can see my code, what I cannot do is to reset the WebView scale to 1 after user changed the scale.

> The reset code should be implement in "DisableZoom" method.

```
public class App extends DroidGap {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        this.appView.addJavascriptInterface(new __Funcs(this.appView), "__FUNCS");

    }
    public class __Funcs{
        WebView appView;
        public __Funcs(WebView appView){
            this.appView = appView;
        }
        public void EnableZoom(){
            this.appView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            this.appView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        }
        public float DisableZoom(){
            this.appView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            this.appView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            this.appView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);

            return this.appView.getScale();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i hoped that "this.appView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);" do something for my issue but it doesn't!

Comment: `getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)` and `getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true)` may what you are searching for

Comment: this.appView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); and

Comment: @207 when ever i am redirecting to another page from index.html the zoom/inch doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to reset the zoom to the initial value is to use the viewport settings for setup of the initial scale and to relaod the page. In my tests for android Phonegap apps  `getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)` only worked, if there have been no settings in place via viewport.